# How to use swagger-ui with service deployed in tomcat running on eclipse

Tags: rest, tomcat, web-applications, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a REST api running at `http://localhost:8080/MyService` and can see the JSON produced by swagger at `http://localhost:8080/MyService/api-docs`. In the Servers project in eclipse I have modified web.xml to include the Cors filter:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

but when I point swagger-ui (loaded in browser from file system) at `http://localhost:8080/MyService/api-docs`, I get the following error:

> Can't read from server. It may not have the appropriate
>   access-control-origin settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the Swagger dist directly to the webapps folder did the trick

Comment: Your solution probably works in most cases, but in general cases no. There is a conflict between newest versions of swagger-jaxrs_2.10 and resteasy-jaxrs. This modification in pom.xml solve a problem
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions></dependency>

Comment: Interesting, thanks for sharing. I was stuck for days before I was able to get this working...

Comment: Hi @RichAshworth please elaborate.I have downloaded the zip of swagger-ui from the github path.Do you mean adding the whole bunch of files under webapps ?

Comment: please give complete details

Comment: Yes - putting all files under webapps worked for me.